# Xpages File Upload control does nothing in 11.0.1

Tags: xpages

I have the same situation as described in post 13572249.  I have an xpage using an application layout.  A custom control uses a Form Table with one row using a File Upload control bound to a rich text field named "Attachments" in a document.  Another row uses a File Download control displayed when an attachment exists.  After selecting a file, pressing a Save button that performs a simple Save Document action along with a full update saves the document, but not the attachment.  The file name in the File Upload control is replaced with "No file chosen".  This was working when my designer client was 9.0.1FP9 and the server was at 9.0.1FP8.  The only change since it was working is the server was upgraded to 11.0.1.

```
<xe:formRow labelPosition="above" label="*Upload:">
    <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{FactSheet.Attachments}" style="width:auto">
    </xp:fileUpload>
</xe:formRow>
<xe:formRow>
    <xp:button value="Save" id="btnSave1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xe:formRow>
<xe:formRow labelPosition="none">
    <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload1"
        value="#{FactSheet.Attachments}" displayLastModified="false"
        displayType="false" displaySize="false" style="width:auto" hideWhen="false">
    </xp:fileDownload>
</xe:formRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

While searching the data\domino\workspace\logs directory, I found several trace-log- files. One of them had multiple occurrences of the following error, the only difference being the file name before ".tmp":

**com.ibm.xsp.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. C:\Windows\TEMP\notesF4DA87\xspupload\upload_0a9f550f_d824_4ba0_a18c_5e17f8495f72_00002451.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified)**

Checking the C:\Windows\TEMP\notesF4DA87 directory showed there was no subdirectory named "xspupload".  Creating it caused the File Upload control to work again. The next question is why wasn't it there already?

Comment: I will recommend a Domino server restart so that Domino can re-create all necessary temp files. The temp files might have been removed by some process outside of Domino as part of a cleanup job?

Comment: I suppose that's possible since it's under C:\Windows\Temp.  There are other subdirectories under notesF4DA87 like xsp, xsppers and xspstate, though they are not empty and contain subdirectories created within the last few days. There are also DTF files that are 3 weeks old.  Would a cleanup job remove the xspupload subdirectory just because it's empty?  I have a monthly therapeutic scheduled reboot that will run next Thursday. I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks.

Comment: After this week's scheduled server reboot, the xspupload directory is still there, though empty, and the file upload control is still working.

Comment: The xspupload directory continues to disappear occasionally.  Even creating a README.TXT file in it doesn't stop it.  I'm checking with our network support vendor, per Per's question, to check whether some process outside Domino is doing this.

Comment: I also experienced this in 12.02FP1